# Map and how to access object key in JS?

Tags: javascript

i'm new to programming , i have map on my code and i want to access object key inside this map , how can i do that ???

```
let person = new Map();       
person.set('name','ahmed');
person.set('age',25);
person.set('salary',80000);
person.set('gender','male');
person.set({name:'red',age:25},'reda')
for (let x of person)     
{                                                                                                                
  console.log(`key ${x[0]} and value ` );     



console.log(person.get('{name:'red',age:25}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store that object somewhere, because it needs to be the exact same object, not just identical:

```js
const key = {name: 'red', age: 25};

person.set(key, 'reda');

console.log(person.get(key));
```

Comment: hi Robo, thank you for your answer it's working but i don't understand that line "because it needs to be the exact same object, not just identical"
console.log(person.get('{name:'red',age:25}')  => this gives me syntax error

Comment: You used nested apostrophes, that's not valid syntax.

Comment: Identical object means the exact same object in memory. You can read about value vs. reference, that should help.